# how to write query which represents group names also

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
Select count(*) from usa.adult group by `income`;
```

income col has mainly two values i.e >50k and <50k

which is found in the result as

[image]

how can i find which value represent >50k and <50k.

desired output:

[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKTKE.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKTKE.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKTKE.png)

Comment: That query alone shouldn't cause a syntax error. Maybe some other text/content is being included with it? Is that long string of underscores some formatting that you've added to your post or part of the response from your client? And what client/platform are you using to run the query?

Comment: mmmm really strange that list of underscore __________________________________________ if you don't know where it comes from try to manipulate it  and replace '_' with ''. I would like to know how do you fill the query string...post it if you can.

Comment: Which "values" of what? Is there another column here besides just `income`?  Please share sample data and desired results so we can better understand what you are after. Perhaps just put `income` in your `SELECT` clause? Like `SELECT income, count(*) FROM usa.adult GROUP BY income;`?

Comment: Can't you just select income? You have it by groups already, so if you want to display those groups, you need to add them to your select.

Comment: It has become another question, but it looks like you and JNevill have it covered :)

Answer (score 0):

as said from  @JNevill extract columns directly

```
Select income, count(*) from usa.adult group by income;
```